# Is $\mathbb{C}(x)$ a finitely-generated $\mathbb{C}[x]$-algebra

Tags: commutative-algebra, finitely-generated

Is $\mathbb{C}(x)$ a finitely-generated $\mathbb{C}[x]$-algebra? Here we can replace $\mathbb{C}$ by any algebraically closed field $k$.

Comment: What does the syntax $K(x)$ mean?

Comment: @AlvinL it's the field of rational functions over $K$, the field of fractions of the polynomial ring $K[x]$.

Comment: Note that given generators, the poles of the elements that they can generate, have to be poles of the generators.

Answer (score 0):

No, otherwise by the transitivity of finitely-generated algebras we will have $\mathbb{C}(x)$ a finitely-generated $\mathbb{C}$-algebra. By Hilbert's Nullstellensatz (If $R$ and $K$ are fields and $R$ is a finitely generated $K-$algebra. Then $R$ is a finite extension of $K$. If $K$ is algebraically closed, then $R=K$) we will have $\mathbb{C}(x)=\mathbb{C}$ , which is absurd. Hence, $\mathbb{C}(x)$ is not a finitely-generated $\mathbb{C}[x]$-algebra.

Comment: This is a nice high-level argument, but it's really overkill: the fact is true if we replace $\mathbb{C}$ by any field (not necessarily algebraically closed),, by a more elementary argument. See, e.g., the answer to the linked duplicate question.